# How to ping the GW of a subnet?

Tags: linux, networking, ping, gateway

There is a variable:

```
SUBNET="10.1.1.0/24"
```

I know that 10.1.1.1 is the GW in this subnet, always the first host.

**Q:** But how can I automate to ping  this GW once? There could be different subnets, ex.: 10.1.1.0/22 when the GW will be 10.1.0.1.

Is there any tool or method on a general Linux distro which I could use to get the first host of a subnet?

Comment: If you have access to nmap, you can do something like " nmap -sL $SUBNET | sed -En '4{s/(^.*)(([[:digit:]]{3}[.]){3}[[:digit:]])(.*$)/\2/p}'" You may have to change sed depending on your output.

Comment: There are several (!) scripts named `ipcalc` that show you various information about network addresses, including the first and last address in a subnet. However, the gateway of a subnet doesn't _have_ to be the first address.  It's a common convention, but it's just that, a convention.